# Solve: $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(1+\sin\left(3x\right)\right)^{\cos\left(x\right)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives

Solve: $$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(1+\sin\left(3x\right)\right)^{\cos\left(x\right)}$$

$y = \lim _{x\to 0}\left(1+\sin\left(3x\right)\right)^{\cos\left(x\right)}$

$\ln(y) = \ln(\lim _{x\to 0}\left(1+\sin\left(3x\right)\right)^{\cos\left(x\right)}$)

$\ln(y) = \lim _{x\to 0}\ln(\left(1+\sin\left(3x\right)\right)^{\cos\left(x\right)})$

$\ln(y) = \lim _{x\to 0}\ln(\cos(x) \times \left(1+\sin\left(3x\right)\right))$

$\ln(y) = \lim _{x\to 0}\ln(\cos(0) \times \left(1+\sin\left(3(0)\right)\right))$

$\ln(y) = \ln(1 \times 1)$

$\ln(y) = \ln(1)$

$\ln(y) = 0$

$y = -\infty$. But if I look at the graph, the limit is actually 1.

Where have I made a mistake?

---

EDIT:

I have:

$\ln(y) = \ln(1)$, so so $y = 1$ (this is right).

But if I solve for $\ln(1)$

Then I get:
$\ln(y) = 0$

and then $y$ is a different value.

Comment: how do you get from line 3 to line 4 (just an example, there are more steps which are questionable)

Comment: $\ln(y)=0\implies y=1$

Comment: Isn't it ln(y) = ln(1)?

Comment: So $y=1$, not negative infinity.

Comment: But then ln(1) = 0, and ln(y) = 0 --> y = negative infinity

Comment: $\ln((1+\sin3x)^{\cos x})=\cos x\ln(1+\sin3x)$, not $\ln(\cos x(1+\sin3x))$

Comment: But you have $\ln(y)=0$!!!  This means $y=1$!!!

Comment: $ln(y) =  ln(1) \implies y=1$

Comment: To solve $\ln(y)=0$, exponentiate both sides (remember that exponentiation and logarithms are inverses). You get $y=e^0=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More simply, just plug $x=0$ into the beginning:

$$(1+\sin(0))^{\cos(0)}=1^1=1$$

Answer (score 0):

The cosine goes out of the logarithm:
$$\ln a^b=b\ln a$$

Note although that this limit can be computed by simple substitution.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f:\mathbb R^+\times \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x,y)=x^y$ is differentiable, since its partial derivatives are $yx^{y-1}$ and $\ln(y)x^y$, which are continuous.

We conclude that the function $f(x,y)$ is continuous. Therefore if we have a sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ that converges to $(1,1)$ then the limit of $f(x_n,y_n)$ is $f(1,1)=1$. In particular your sequence is $(1+\sin(3x),\cos(x))$. So the limit is $1$.

---

I'm pretty sure that any Actual proof that the limit exists is going to have to pass through some arguments similar to those used in proving this theorem:

A function $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ which has all of its partial derivatives, and which satisfies that they are all continuous, is differentiable.